# Could there have been advantages to extending an invitation to North Korea to observe the Belt and Road Initiative?

Tags: china, north-korea, belt-and-road-initiative

Could there have been advantages to extending an invitation to North Korea to observe the Belt and Road Initiative?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belt_and_Road_Initiative

> Observers
>
> ```
>  North Korea[72]
> ```

https://www.ndtv.com/world-news/china-invites-north-korea-to-belt-and-road-summit-2025537

> China said Friday leaders from 37 nations and North Korean
> representatives will attend a summit for its Belt and Road Initiative
> next week as it hit back at criticism of the massive trade
> infrastructure project.

China invited North Korea to be an observer, but I can't see any good reason to do so. North Korea is a nation under heavy sanctions that doesn't have strong relation with many countries, and it's a pariah state, so North Korea being invited as an observer won't give legitimacy to the project, and I am under serious impression that this move doesn't really have a purpose or yield any significant benefits.

Comment: Maybe it is more for the benefit of NK than for the Belt and Road Initiative. See, if you behaved in a way that would put you on every sanctions list, than you could participate in nice things like this.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:**
>
> Could there have been advantages to extending an invitation to North Korea to observe the Belt and Road Initiative?

North Korea is a close ally of China.  It's North Korea's closest military and economic ally.  Given North Korea shares a border with China and already has infrastructure in place to facilitate the large trade shared between the two nations, North Korea is not dependent, nor necessary as a belt and road participant.  It's still polite and smart for China to invite them; as North Korea is rather sensitive about being excluded from such summits, especially by their friends.